# Is there a way for a Fragment to receive Intent data without going through an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, unity-game-engine, android-intent, nfc

I come from the world of Unity3D development and I'm pretty new to Android development. I'm trying to create an NFC plugin for Unity Android. I followed [this guide](https://tapintonfc.org/2014/11/developer-tip-how-to-use-nfc-with-unity-3d-in-android-devices/), provided by Twinsprite, on how to create the plugin by extending `UnityPlayerActivity`. Using Twinsrpite's code, the plugin enables Android's NFC Foreground Dispatch System in order to capture the NFC Intent while my application is in the foreground.

In my research I've found that extending `UnityPlayerActivity` is frowned upon because it can cause a lot of problems with dependencies in other plugins in your Unity project. From there I decided that I would have my plugin extend the `Fragment` class as many other Unity Android plugins do. This way my headless `Fragment` plugin can take advantage of the Fragment Lifecycle's callbacks without causing issues in Unity down the line.

I ran into an issue while modifying the code to work on a `Fragment`, though. Twinsprite's code relies on the `Activity`'s `onNewIntent` callback that then passes the `Intent`'s data into a handler method that parses the NFC message. Since I'm writing the code to use a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`, I no longer have access to the `onNewIntent` callback so I can't call the handler method anymore. As stated above, I'd like to stay away from extending `UnityPlayerActivity` so I'm left with this question:

How can I receive the data from my NFC `Intent` from within my `Fragment` plugin without extending `UnityPlayerActivity`?

Comment: Fragments must be hosted inside an Activity. They are not standalone components

Comment: @Kuffs I don't have the code on me at the moment, but I'm having my Fragment add itself to `UnityPlayerActivity`'s state by using the `FragmentManager` class. I'm doing this by calling a static method within Unity to create my plugin object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go the route of just extending `UnityPlayerActivity` without the use of the `Fragment` class. The point of the `Fragment` extension plugin was to avoid having to change the AndroidManifest.xml because I'm afraid that it will cause problems with other plugins i.e. analytics, Facebook, etc. `Intent`s must be handled by an `Activity` so what I was trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a method to your Fragment which the activity can pass the new Intent to. Then the fragment can process the intent as desired.

```
MyUnityFragment myUnityFragment;

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);    
    myUnityFragment.newIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way to circumvent writing any code on the Activity's side. Wondering if there was a public event one could subscribe to when the user receives an Intent, but it looks like there's so such way of doing that so I'll just have to fallback on this original idea. Thanks.

Comment: apologies I didn't realise you couldn't extend the activity as the linked example did extend the activity. I'm afraid the NFC functionality is linked to the activity, see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#dispatching

Comment: The unity docs don't seem to make a big deal about extending the provided activity, seems you just have to update the manifest. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.html

Comment: The idea of staying away from extending `UnityPlayerActivity` came from warning from the author of [this tutorial](http://eppz.eu/blog/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-1/) on Unity Android plugins. It definitely looks like I might have to end up following the Unity docs. In your experience, have you seen any problems extending `UnityPlayerActivity` and then integrating other plugins at a later time e.g. Facebook, Vuforia, etc.?

Comment: I can't help more as I don't have any experience extending from UnityPlayerActivity.

Comment: I fell back on what the example did and am just extending `UnityPlayerActivity` without creating the a `Fragment`. I appreciate that you actually responded to my question. Thanks :)